# Differential Equation $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2 + 1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\left( \dfrac{dy}{dx} \right)^2 + 1 \quad \text{and} \quad y(0)=\dfrac{dy}{dx}(0)=0 \quad \text{on} \quad \left( \dfrac{\pi}{2},-\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$$

---

Let's define $u=\frac{dy}{dx} \implies \frac{du}{dx}=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$.
$$\frac{du}{dx} = u^2+1 \implies \int \frac{1}{u^2+1}\;du = \int dx$$

Thus, 
$$\arctan{u} = x + K_1 \iff u = \tan{(x + K_1)} $$

We integrate again,
$$\int \frac{dy}{dx} \; dx = \int \tan{(x + K_1)} \; dx \implies y = \ln{(\cos{(x + K_1)})} + K_2$$

How can I evaluate the particular solution?

Comment: $\tan K_1=0$ and so ...

Comment: How can you know that $\tan{(K_1)}=0$?

Comment: compute $y'(x)$ and take $x=0$.

Comment: I don't understand, can you show me your steps?

Comment: I leave it to you. Sometimes you really need to make an effort, you do learn more.

Comment: @hlapointe: $u(0)=0$, no ?

Answer (score 1):

The ODE $u'=1+u^2$ has as its solutions the functions $u(x)=\tan(x-c)$, as you have found out yourself. Since we want $u(0)=y'(0)=0$ we necessarily have $c=0$, so that we finally obtain
$$y(x)=y(0)+\int_0^x u(t)\>dt=\int_0^x\tan t\>dt=\log(\sec x)\qquad\left(-{\pi\over2}<x<{\pi\over2}\right)\ .$$